# Varnish + zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, varnish, varnish-vcl

How to config `Varnish` with `Zend framework 1`?

What `.vcl` config file must be? Could anyone give some examples?

Thank you.

Comment: The .vcl will be dependant on your application routes, i.e. which URL is the one generating cookie (login page). Which URLs are meant for authenticated users and guests.

Answer (score 0):

You must know very well how HTTP methods and headers work. See here a great [article](http://2ndscale.com/rtomayko/2008/things-caches-do)

And here a generic VCL boilerplate [here](https://github.com/mattiasgeniar/varnish-4.0-configuration-templates)